# Como crear una expresion regular para validar JS?

Tags: javascript

Quiero hacer una expresión regular que me valide el campo `Lot` de mi formulario.

El `lot` tiene una longitud de 6 dígitos siempre, lo que puede variar es que después del sexto dígito este puede tener una letra de la A-Z.

Tengo ya la parte sencilla que es validar desde el inicio de la cadena que sean números hasta un limite permitido, quedando mi expresión así:

```
let regular = /^([0-9]){1,10}$/;
```

Buscando si hay coincidencias desde el primer carácter hasta el décimo que seria el limite.

¿Como hago para que desde el séptimo carácter valide si hay alguna letra de la A-Z? Y si no hay que lo deje pasar, es decir: `203945A true, 2039481 true, 39482849 false` (longitud 7 de números).

Comment: Buenas. Una opción sería esta `^([0-9]){6}([A-Z]){0,1}$`. Siendo solo mayúsculas, si quisieras mayus y minus pues [a-Z]. Espero que sea lo que buscas.

Comment: @MarioMonterde en tu comentario dices: `[a-Z]`, pero eso no compila a una RegExp válida en Javascript, en todo caso debe ser: `[a-zA-Z]`. Ojo con eso. Saludos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
let regular = /^\d{6}[a-zA-Z]?$/;
```

Buscamos cualquier dígito seis veces y opcionalmente un carácter en el rango a-z A-Z.

Comment: ¿No llevaría una interrogación antes del $ para decir que la letra es opcional? `/^\d{6}[a-zA-Z]?$/`

Comment: Cierto jotaelesalinas, corrijo la respuesta.